# PHP equivalent of Javascript %

Tags: javascript, php, code-migration

I am converting these functions http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html to PhP so they can be run server side.

I have the following line of code in Javascript (line 201)

```
alpha1 = (brng13 - brng12 + Math.PI) % (2*Math.PI) - Math.PI;
```

and so far in php I have got

```
 $alpha1 = ($brng13 - $brng12 + pi()) % (2*pi()) - pi();
```

However I do not know what that `%` stands for in Javascript and what its equivalent conversion into PHP would be.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should learn Javascript before trying to translate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%` is the same in PHP and JS, the Modulus operator, aka the remainder.

eg:

```
10 % 9 = 1
10 % 8 = 2
10 % 7 = 3
10 % 6 = 4
10 % 5 = 0
10 % 4 = 2
10 % 3 = 1
10 % 2 = 0
10 % 1 = 0
```

Comment: Thanks Sammitch. My grasp of maths is about equal to that of Javascript and your answer is most educational

Answer (score 1):

That's the [modulus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators).  PHP uses the [same thing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php).  (Come to think of it, I don't know of a language that doesn't.)

Of course, running these two code samples and seeing the runtime values would indicate pretty clearly if the operators are doing the same thing...

Comment: mysql's sql, for one. `mod(7,2)`.

Comment: Thanks David.  I ran the code snippets side by side and the PhP version was giving a different geolocation.  Removing the % condition resolved it but I was just wondering what it did.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript operators: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators

PHP operators: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

The % operator is called the modulus operator, or the "remainder" operator. It is common to many programming languages and as far as I know performs the same operation in both Javascript and PHP. Either of the links above should lead you to a good definition of what it does.